# Ada: How to define a random constant?

Tags: random, constants, ada

I am currently working through John English' "Ada 95: The Craft of Object-Oriented Programming". I am at [task 5.1](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/docs/craft/html/ch05.htm#5.ex):

> Write a program to play a simple guessing game. Define an integer type with a range of values from 1 to 1000 and declare a secret value as a constant of this type, and then give the user ten chances to guess its value.

What I wrote (as a stub) was now

```
procedure je_5_1 is
  type guess_value is new Integer range 1..1000;
  secret : guess_value;
  package random_guess_value is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(guess_value);
  Gen : random_guess_value.Generator;
begin
  random_guess_value.Reset(Gen);
  secret := random_guess_value.Random(Gen);
end je_5_1;
```

Obviously this does not implement the requirement to `declare a secret value as a constant`. But since I have to call `Reset(Gen)` before I can assign a randomly generated value to `secret`, I cannot define the variable `secret` as a constant before `begin`.

Is it still possible to define `secret` as a random constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a "declare" to open new scope. For example:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Example is

   package Integer_Text_IO is new Integer_IO (Integer);
   use Integer_Text_IO;

   A : Integer;

begin

   Get(A);

   declare
      C : constant Integer := A; 
   begin
      Put(C);
   end;

end Example;
```

I think that what the text says is that you should choose the secret value when you write your code and insert it "hard coded" into the source.

Comment: Yes, that worked! But no, the (complete) exercise explicitly says to use a RNG. I just truncated the text to focus on my main problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [exercise](http://archive.adaic.com/docs/craft/html/ch05.htm#5.ex) later suggests that you "Modify the program so that the value to be guessed is chosen at random each time the program is run." This requires that the [`Generator`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-5-2.html) be initialized *before* the secret value is established. One approach is to encapsulate the secret value in an [*Abstract State Machine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_state_machines), illustrated [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Packages#Two_Flavors_of_Package). In the example below, an instance of the `Generator` is `Reset` and used to initialize `Secret` in a sequence of statements that is executed when the package is elaborated, as discussed [here](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-7-2.html) and illustrated [here](http://archive.adaic.com/docs/craft/html/ch04.htm#4.7).

```
package Game_Model is
   subtype Guess_Value is Integer range 1 .. 1000;
   function Check(value : Guess_Value) return Boolean;
end Game_Model;

package body Game_Model is
   package Guess_Generator is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(Guess_Value);
   G: Guess_Generator.Generator;
   Secret : Guess_Value;

   function Check(Value : Guess_Value) return Boolean is
   begin
      return Value = Secret;
   end;

begin
   Guess_Generator.Reset(G);
   Secret := Guess_Generator.Random(G);
end Game_Model;
```

Given a guessed `Value`, you can `Check` it as required in your program.

```
Value : Game_Model.Guess_Value;
…
Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Boolean'Image(Game_Model.Check(Value)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You might create another procedure inside the declaration part of the main procedure that would return the random number.

```
procedure je_5_1 is
  type guess_value is new Integer range 1..1000;

  function get_random return guess_value
  is
     package random_guess_value is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(guess_value);
     Gen : random_guess_value.Generator;
  begin
     random_guess_value.Reset(Gen);
     return random_guess_value.Random(Gen);
  end get_random;

  secret : constant guess_value := get_random;
begin
   --do your 10 chance loop
end je_5_1;
```